# Can't run Play in dev mode under Ubuntu

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.5

I've tried to run the project 'play-scala' from activator projects with the following:
ran 'activator new' a console, choosed 'play-scala' template, 'activator run' in the project folder.

But I always get the exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$38$$anonfun$apply$39$$anonfun$29.apply(Defaults.scala:749)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$38$$anonfun$apply$39$$anonfun$29.apply(Defaults.scala:749)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$38$$anonfun$apply$39.apply(Defaults.scala:749)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$runTask$1$$anonfun$apply$38$$anonfun$apply$39.apply(Defaults.scala:748)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)

My env:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Scala 2.12.1, sbt 0.13.13, OpenJDK 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14.

Comment: Which example from that vast activator catalogue are you running? That error is so generic and you haven't provided any other relevant information. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Play-scala template.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed by removing the folder .sbt  in home directory.